# .sort and .sort.limit not showing document in same order

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, mongo-shell

I am new to MongoDB and running some basic command.

Below is a command with basic filter. I am just sorting the documents on the basis of Company & this is the first10 records.

[image: Command with filter of "Company" field]

Now I ran the same command and put a limit of 10  & same sorting criteria i.e. `Company`. Now I assume that `limit` keyword is used when we want only given number of documents.

Below is the output :-

[image: Sort with Limit]

Now the records are same but not in same order. I think that even in second case the sorting will happen in same order and thus the top 10 documents shall be same. Why is it not so ?

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/method/cursor.sort/#behavior